# R package 'haven' read_spss: how to make it ignore value labels?

Tags: r, attributes, label, r-haven

I have an SPSS file. I read it in using 'haven' package:

```
library(haven)
spss1 <- read_spss("SPSS_Example.sav")
```

I created a function that extracts the long labels (in SPSS - "Label"):

```
fix_labels <- function(x, TextIfMissing) {
      val <- attr(x, "label")
      if (is.null(val)) TextIfMissing else val
}
longlabels <- sapply(spss1, fix_labels, TextIfMissing = "NO LABLE IN SPSS")
```

Looks like a little bug in 'haven':

When I actually look at the attributes of one variable that has no
long label in SPSS but has Value Labels, I am getting:

```
attr(spss1$WAVE, "label")
NULL
```

But when I sapply my function longlabels to my data frame and ask it
to print the long labels for each column, for the same column "WAVE" I
am getting - instead of NULL:

```
NULL
VERY/SOMEWHAT FAMILIAR    NOT AT ALL FAMILIAR
                     1                      2
```

This is, of course, incorrect, because it grabs the next attribute
(which one?) and replaces NULL with it.

This function is supposed to create a vector of long labels and
usually it does, e.g.:

```
str(longlabels)
 Named chr [1:64] "Serial number" ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:64] "Respondent_Serial" "weight" "r7_1" "r7_2" ...
```

However, I just got an SPSS file with 92 columns and ran exactly the
same function on it. Now, I am getting not a vector, but a list

```
str(longlabels)
List of 92
 $ VEHRATED      : chr "VEHICLE RATED"
 $ RESPID        : chr "RESPONDENT ID"
 $ RESPID8       : chr "8 DIGIT RESPONDENT NUMBER"
```

An observation about the structure of longlabels here: those columns
that do NOT have a long lable in SPSS but DO have Values (value
labels) - for them my function grabs their value labels, so that now
my long label is recorded as a numeric vector with names, e.g.:

```
 $ AWARE2        : Named num [1:2] 1 2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "VERY/SOMEWHAT FAMILIAR" "NOT AT ALL FAMILIAR"
```

Question: How could I avoid the extraction of the Value Labels for the
columns that have no long labels?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution. The problem was partial matching in attr():

```
fix_labels <- function(x, TextIfMissing) {
      val <- attr(x, "label", exact = TRUE)
      if (is.null(val)) TextIfMissing else val
}
```